# Coldfusion10 + Apache web server

Tags: apache, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am running an install of Coldfusion10 on my local Windows7 machine. I now want to configure it to serve the site on apache web server (primarily I want to use the apache mod_rewrite functionality to rewrite urls).

However, once I have configured Coldfusion to use Apache (via the web server configuration tool) my apache service is stopped and I cannot restart it.

On restarting I get this error:

```
Syntax error on line 2 of C:/apache/apache2/conf/mod_jk.conf:
cannot load C:/coldfusion10/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.so into server: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I have tried re-downloading the mod_jk.so file that should work with my version of apache, and whilst that stops the above error being shown, me apache server still doesn start.

Anyone experienced this or have any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: Please share line 2 of mod_jk.conf.

Comment: And also post Apache full version info and OS type (32 or 64)

Comment: You may get a better response from serverfault.com (where non-programming server questions like this one are asked).